# apex repeat on multiple list values with one common id

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, list, repeat

I have 2 lists `list<Attachment>` and `list<Calls__C>`.

The relation is `Attachment.parentid=CAlls__c.Account__C`. Now I want single repeat that will traverse through these two lists in pageblocktable.

```
column1> Calls__c.name 
column2> CAlls__c.Account__r.name
Column3> Attachment.ParentId
Column4> Attachment.Id
```

Please find the apex page & controller as Kevin suggested. I guess controller is fine,page having some issue.
Apex page:

```
<apex:page controller="attachmentCallsWrapper_parent">
<apex:panelGrid columns="5" border="1" >
  <apex:dataTable value="{!callWrapper}" var="cw">
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header" >SEQ</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cw.sequence}" />
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header" >Call Name</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cw.callName}" />
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header" >Account Name</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cw.accountName}" />
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header" >Call Id</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cw.callId}" />
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header" >Attachment Id</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cw.attachmentId}" />
  </apex:column>
  </apex:dataTable>
</apex:panelgrid>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class attachmentCallsWrapper_parent{

public void attachmentCallsWrapper_parent(){}

public  List<attachmentCallsWrapper> callWrapper {get;set;}
public list<CAll2_vod__C> mycalls=[select id,name,account_vod__C from CAll2_vod__C where account_vod__C=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ];

// construct a map for calls/attachments
// using set to avoid duplicate attachmentIds, unlikely, if any happened to be found

map<id,set<attachment>> mapCallAttachments = new map<id,set<attachment>>();
public void method1(){
for (Attachment atf : [Select Id,Name from attachment where parentId = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')]) {
  if (mapCallAttachments.containsKey(atf.ParentId)) {
    set<attachment> satf = mapCallAttachments.get(atf.ParentId);
    satf.add(atf);
    mapCallAttachments.put(atf.ParentId,satf);
  } else {
    set<attachment> satf = new set<attachment>();
    satf.add(atf);
    mapCallAttachments.put(atf.ParentId,satf);
  }
}

// using map, re-iterate through list
for (Call2_vod__c c : myCalls) {
  if (mapCallAttachments.containskey(c.Id)) {
    set<attachment> satf = mapCallAttachments.get(c.Id);
    for (attachment atf : satf) {
      attachmentCallsWrapper cw = new attachmentCallsWrapper(c,atf);
      cw.sequence = callWrapper.size()+1;
      callWrapper.add(cw);
    }
  } else {
   attachmentCallsWrapper cw = new attachmentCallsWrapper(c,null);
   cw.sequence = callWrapper.size()+1;
  callWrapper.add(cw);
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to display in pageblocktable? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely think the wrapper class is the way to go; I use this method a lot especially as it helps to avoid view state issues.

I would recommend not showing record Ids, and instead provide a hyperlink on the name references. This would reduce your visible output to the user considerably. For those, you can make use of std html a href tags, or use apex link options.. I'll leave that to the imagination for now.

**VF**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="caseAttach_controller" >

<style>
.rowOdd  { background-color: #B5B5BA; }
.rowEven { background-color: #CFD6E1; }
</style>

<apex:sectionheader title = "Case Attachments" />

<apex:pageblock>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseWrapper}" rowClasses="rowOdd,rowEven" var="cw">
  <apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header" >SEQ</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cw.sequence}" />
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header" >Account Name</apex:facet>
    <a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.AccountId}" id="{!cw.AccountId}" 
      target="_blank" onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.AccountId}').hide();" 
      onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.AccountId}', '{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.AccountId}/m?retURL=%2F{!cw.AccountId}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" 
      onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.AccountId}').hide();" 
      onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.AccountId}', '{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.AccountId}/m?retURL=%2F{!cw.AccountId}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!cw.AccountName}</a> 
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header" >Case Number</apex:facet>
    <a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.CaseId}" id="{!cw.CaseId}" 
      target="_blank" onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.CaseId}').hide();" 
      onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.CaseId}', '{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.CaseId}/m?retURL=%2F{!cw.CaseId}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" 
      onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.CaseId}').hide();" 
      onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!cw.CaseId}', '{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.CaseId}/m?retURL=%2F{!cw.CaseId}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">{!cw.caseNumber}</a> 
  </apex:column>

  <apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header" >Attachments</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputLink target="blank" value="{!cw.downloadLink}" >{!cw.AttachmentName}</apex:outputLink>
    <!--<apex:outputLink value="{!$Site.Prefix}/{!cw.attachmentId}" >{!cw.AttachmentName}</apex:outputLink>-->

  </apex:column>

  </apex:pageBlockTable>

  </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

public with sharing class CaseAttach_Controller {

```
  transient public List<attachmentCaseWrapper> caseWrapper {get; set;}

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                
  public CaseAttach_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    List<Case> listCases = new List<Case>();
    // populate listCases with your records (ie, cases by account for last n days

    caseWrapper = new List<attachmentCaseWrapper>();

    // construct a map for calls/attachments
    // using set to avoid duplicate attachmentIds, unlikely, if any happened to be found

    map<id,set<attachment>> mapCaseAttachments = new map<id,set<attachment>>();

    for (Attachment atf : [Select Id,Name,ParentId from attachment where parentId in :listCases]) {
      if (mapCaseAttachments.containsKey(atf.ParentId)) {
         set<attachment> satf = mapCaseAttachments.get(atf.ParentId);
         satf.add(atf);
         mapCaseAttachments.put(atf.ParentId,satf);
       } else {
         set<attachment> satf = new set<attachment>();
         satf.add(atf);
         mapCaseAttachments.put(atf.ParentId,satf);
       }
     } // for

    // using map, re-iterate through list
    for (Case c : listCases) {
      if (mapCaseAttachments.containskey(c.Id)) {
        set<attachment> satf = mapCaseAttachments.get(c.Id);
        for (attachment atf : satf) {
          attachmentCaseWrapper cw = new attachmentCaseWrapper(c,atf);
          cw.sequence = caseWrapper.size()+1;
          caseWrapper.add(cw);
        }
      } else {
        attachmentCaseWrapper cw = new attachmentCaseWrapper(c,null);
        cw.sequence = caseWrapper.size()+1;
        caseWrapper.add(cw);
      } 
    } // for
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                
  // The first part of the wrapper are the elements that you would need for the page:
  // (the ordering is not important)

  public class attachmentCaseWrapper {
    public integer sequence      {get; set;} 
    public string caseNumber     {get; set;}
    public string accountName    {get; set;}
    public string accountId      {get; set;}
    public string caseId         {get; set;}
    public string attachmentId   {get; set;}
    public string attachmentName {get; set;}
    public string downloadLink   {get; set;}
    // the second part of the wrapper accepts the parameters and assigns values
    // to the above class variables

    public attachmentCaseWrapper (Case cse, Attachment atf) {
      caseNumber = cse.CaseNumber;
      accountName = cse.Account.Name;
      accountId = cse.Account.Id;
      caseId = cse.Id;
      if (atf != null) {
        attachmentId = atf.Id;
        attachmentName = atf.Name;
        downloadLink = 'https://c.cs11.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + atf.Id;
      } 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin the page is having some issue. I am unable to find out.I have used your suggestion in controller .I think it is working fine.Please find the page I have used.

Comment: Hi Saikat; understandably the former sample was pseudo code; I mocked this up for use with cases, as it would be natively usable for anyone; just retouch case references to your call object references..

Comment: Hi Kevin. The wrapper class is not returning attachment in image format. It should return the signature.Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 2):

As @kcshafer points out, this can be done with maps and inner lists. This will let you group the lists by a parent key.

Though I think your model may be flawed, as it presumes a one-to-one relationship between the Attachment on the Account and a Calls__c record. This may get you started...

**Apex**

```
// create the maps
Map<Id, List<Attachment>> accountAttachmentsMap = new Map<Id, List<Attachment>>();
Map<Id, List<Calls__c>> accountCallsMap = new Map<Id, List<Calls__c>>();

// populate the map from your list
for (Attachment a : attachmentList) {

    // check to see if there is already an inner list
    if (accountAttachmentsMap.isEmpty()) {

        // create the map entry and init with a populated list
        accountAttachmentsMap.put(a.ParentId, new List<Attachment>{ a });
    } else {

        // get the list from the map and add to it
        accountAttachmentsMap.get(a.ParentId).add(a);
    }

}

// populate the map from your list
for (Calls__c c : callsList) {

    // check to see if there is already an inner list
    if (accountCallsMap.isEmpty()) {

        // create the map entry and init with a populated list
        accountCallsMap.put(c.Account__c, new List<Calls__c>{ c });
    } else {

        // get the list from the map and add to it
        accountCallsMap.get(c.Account__c).add(c);
    }

}
```

**VF**

```
<!-- repeat over the keyset from a map, use array notation to get the column data -->
<!-- there are two tables as the inner lists can vary in size -->
<apex:repeat value="{!accountCallsMap}" var="accountId">
    <apex:outputText value="{!accountId}" />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountCallsMap[accountId]}" var="calls">
        <apex:column value="{!calls.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!calls.Account__r.Name}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountAttachmentsMap[accountId]}" var="att">
        <apex:column value="{!att.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!att.ParentId}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would utilize a simple class structure to iterate through on the vf page, though maps could also accomplish this. I made a simple example below of how I would go about this.

```
public class MyController{
    List<AttachmentCallsWrapper> att_calls {get;set;}

    public MyController(){
        this.att_calls = new List<AttachmentCallsWrapper>();
        //fill list
    }

    public class AttachmentCallsWrapper {
        public Call__c call {get;set;}
        public Attachment att {get;set;}

        public AttachmentCallsWrapper(Attachment a, Call__c c){
            this.call = Call__c;
            this.att = a;
        }
    }
}

<apex:repeat value="{!att_calls}" var="ac">
    <apex:outputText value="{!ac.call.Field}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!ac.att.Field}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```